# operators overload weird output

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, operator-keyword

I am new to C++ and as a practice I made a fraction class "Frac". Everything seems to work fine except when I want to print the result of operations like (a+b), a and b being Frac objects. In my main function, I use:

```
 Frac a(5, 2), b(9, 2), c(a+b); //Three fractions a=5/2, b=9/2, and c = a+b = 14/2 = 7/1
  cout << (a+b) << endl; //This line's result makes no sense to me : always 2686600/4201035
  cout << c << endl; //This line's result is ok : 7/1
```

Here is how I overloaded operator<< :

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &stream, Fract const& a){
  stream << a.getNum() << "/" << a.getDenom(); //Num is numerator of fraction a, Denom is its denominator

  return stream;
}
```

operator+ :

```
Fract& operator+(Fract const& a, Fract const& b){
  Fract copy(a);
  copie += b;
  return copy;
}
```

operator+= :

```
Fract& Fract::operator+=(Fract const& b){
  Fract copy(b);
  //Put on same denominator for add
  copy.m_denom *= m_denom;
  copy.m_num *= m_denom;
  m_denom *= b.m_denom;
  m_num *= b.m_denom;
  //Now on same denominator
  m_num += copy.m_num;
  Fract::simplify();

  return *this;
}
```

The getters :

```
int Fract::getDenom() const{return m_denom;}

int Fract::getNum() const{return m_num;}
```

When I debug the program, everything is fine until this line in operator<< :

```
  stream << a.getNum() << "/" << a.getDenom();
```

Before its execution, the values of a.m_num and a.m_denom are good (7 and 1, checked with debugger), but after the first call (a.getDenom() here), a.m_num and a.m_denom switch from 7 and 1 to 2686600 and 4201035! It is the same thing no matter the operator, so ...

```
  Fract a(5,2), b(9,2);
  cout << (a+b) << endl << (a*b) << endl << (a/b) << endl << (a-b);
```

... 's output is :

```
2686600/4201035
2686600/4201035
2686600/4201035
2686600/4201035
```

and ...

```
  Fract a(5,2), b(9,2), c(a+b), d(a*b), e(a/b), f(a-b);
  cout << c << endl << d << endl << e << endl << f;
```

... 's output is :

```
7/1
45/4
5/9
-2/1
```

All correct results...

This drove me crazy. I searched for hours but did not find the solution or someone who had the same problem. It would be realy nice if someone could help me.
Thank you guys.

Comment: Probably shouldn't overload operator<<, it leads to a lot of ambiguity for anyone else trying to read the code. You should define a `print()` function inside Frac that writes what you want to cout.

Comment: @ZachStark That's an option, but I really wanted to spot the problem, I would have felt bad to just bypass it :p Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Fract& operator+(Fract const& a, Fract const& b){
    Fract copy(a);
    ...
    return copy;
}
```

You're returning a reference to a local variable but when that variable expires all the data is gone. You should be returning by value:

```
Frac operator+(...)
```

Comment: +1 Note to OP. Standard operator `+` and `-`, etc. generally return by-value constructions of the resulting operation; not references. The accumulation operators `+=`, `-=`, etc. are the ones that generally return such references, but be careful when doing so. (and nice answer, sir).

Comment: Ho my god... Thank you very much! You made it clear and short :D
Should I delete this post?
@WhozCraig Thanks for the details :)

Comment: @mebs No. If your problem has been solved, you *accept* the answer that you believe helped you the most. :)